# GIT multipule branches with OSGI

Tags: maven, osgi, git-svn

**Dear All,**

I'm new to GIT and i want to move from SVN to GIT, in my application I'm using web services, for each web service i have bundle for API, bundle for IMpl, and another for service.

I want to make branches for each web service to contain service and WS-Impl. and another branch that will contain all WS-API. the reason is to limit access to the code.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to apply access rights, then i would suggest to put the API projects in separate Git repositories. Branches aren't there for this case. So you would have one repository for the API project and one repository for Impl and Service.

Comment: different branches are not enough to seal off different code bases